# PyLint: how to make pylint fail if code rating is not above some defined threshold rating

Tags: python, pylint, buildbot

I'm using Pylint in buildbot's build step and i want the build should stop if certain code quality doesn't meet

```
BitBucketFactory.addStep(steps.PyLint(command=['pylint', '--py3k', '--ignore=ln2sql',
                                                '--disable=C,import-error,import-error,too-few-public-methods,undefined-variable',
                                                'swagger_server'],
                                    haltOnFailure=True))
```

Comment: possible copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944575/how-to-set-a-pylint-score-threshold.