# Pylint used as pre-commit hook not accepting --fail-under flag

Tags: python, pylint, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a pre-commit set up on a python repo. I have a .pre-commit-config.yaml file where I specify my pylint settings/arguments. Previously my pylint hook worked.

Pylint config in .pre-commit-config.yaml:

```
  - repo: local
    hooks:
     - id: pylint
       name: pylint
       entry: pylint
       language: system
       types: [python]
       args:
        [
          "-rn",
          "--rcfile=./polestar.rc",
          "--fail-under=6"
        ]
```

This config previously worked. Now I get the following error.

```
pylint: error: no such option: --fail-under
```

I can't think of anything that has changed to cause this issue.

Any advice would be great or suggestions as to what could fix it.

Comment: Same question, but unanswered: [fail-under flag does not work with pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67456882/1256452)

Comment: See also [this closed issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2242) which implies that pylint never has and never will have `--fail-under`. Yet [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50944575/1256452) says that it's there in 2.5.0 and later. Presumably there are multiple different programs called "pylint" at this point. (In any case this has nothing to do with Git.)

Answer (score 1):

Found issue: the python environment I was in had a old version of pylint installed. I updated the pylint version to latest and the option to set --fail-under became available again.